# Does postgresql have native support for a HA cluster?

Tags: postgresql

The question here addresses the part of the service compared to a **MySQL InnoDB** HA cluster (single primary) where we have **MySQL-router** to complement this setup.

Whereof what I found so far it was only 3rd party tools that help with reaching such a setup, with no clear enough documentation.

thank you.

Comment: Yes it does. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/high-availability.html

Comment: https://severalnines.com/database-blog/how-deploy-postgresql-high-availability it does. you can choose as per your requirement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you share a proper setup that mentions a production-grade high-availability multi-node setup?

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA several nines has its own platform. I want something that suits an on-prem setup.

Comment: @nour. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/high-availability.html)  explains how to setup a production grade HA environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't have any clusterware built in. You will need thrid-party software like Patroni for that.